Is there a name for these kind of matrices?
Is there a specific name for matrices, where each column of the matrix is (the same multiple of) a standard unit vector?
Here is an example of such a matrix:
\begin{equation*}
\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0 & 1\\
0 & 1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & \alpha \\
0 & \alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Where I come across these matrices is when there are several ones of this kind such that the scalars sum up to one. For instance, for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & \alpha \\
0 & \alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0& 1-\alpha \\
1-\alpha & 1-\alpha & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
As the examples illustrate, the columns do not have to span the whole space. Matrices can be square or rectangular as long as number of rows is equal to or larger than number of columns.

The only name I can think of in this context are binary matrices. So we have $\alpha A+(1-\alpha) B$ for two binary matrices $A$ and $B$.

If we restrict to the case $\alpha=1$, then such a matrix is induced by a map of ${1,\ldots,n}$ to itself. In the special case that such a map is a permutation, we call the matrix a permutation matrix. So a nice name for your matrices could be coined from a nice name for general maps of a finite set to itself ... I don't think there is one.

Here I have one: "scalar multiple of a deterministic left stochastic matrix"

A "left stochastic" matrix is a matrix with nonnegative real entries such that each column sum equals $1$. It can be used to describe a Markov process, the entries being transisition probabilities between $n$ states.
"deterministic" because said Markov process doesn't actually involve randomness
"scalar multiple" to account for your $\alpha$

However, this would not be fully adequate for non-square matrices.
So how about "scalar multiple of the incidence matrix of a function"?

Each column in the matrices you provided is probably a standard unit vector, but its structure closely relates to rank-1 matrices or elementary matrices in linear algebra.
Here are some key characteristics of the these matrices:

Elementary Matrices: These matrices resemble elementary matrices, but are scaled.

Rank-1 Matrices: Each column is scaled individually.


